# Created a file S3Service but can't seem to load it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a simple file S3Service.rb

```
/lib/s3_service.rb
```

The file has:

require 'aws-sdk'

```
class S3Service
  attr_accessor :region

  def initialize
    @region = 'us-east-1c'
  end

  def foo
    puts "region is #{region}"
  end
end
```

When I go into rails console I can't seem to be able to use this class.

```
>rails c
>require 'S3Service'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- S3Service
```

Are numbers not allowed in names?

I can create instances of other classes that I have in my lib folder so it is loading all my lib files correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` takes the name of the file (optionally and conventionally without the `.rb` extension), not the name of the class.  So you should change the require to:

```
require 's3_service'
```